# How to plot coordinate system from EPSG 4326 on north pole centered map in Python?

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib, pandas, cartopy

I have the following pandas dataframe (df) which looks like this with column headers and data values, 3 points each:

```
temperature: array([-101.6015625, -100.9296875,  -85.4296875])
latitude: array([32.54681317, 32.81152175, 30.30341752])
longitude: array([-101.6015625, -100.9296875,  -85.4296875])
```

Using these following imports:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
```

When I run this code snippet:

```
d = {'temperature': [-101.6015625, -100.9296875,  -85.4296875], 'latitude': [32.54681317, 32.81152175, 30.30341752], 'longitude': [-101.6015625, -100.9296875,  -85.4296875]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.reset_index()
geom = [Point(x,y) for x, y in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geom)
gdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax11 = fig1.add_subplot(121, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax11.coastlines()
ax21 = fig1.add_subplot(121)
ax21.set_frame_on(False)
ax21.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax21.yaxis.set_visible(False)
gdf.plot(ax=ax21)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.margins(y=10)
ax11.set_xlim(ax21.get_xlim())
ax11.set_ylim(ax21.get_ylim())
plt.show()
```

I get the following output:
[image]

However, when I run the following to centre the map over the North Pole,

```
d = {'temperature': [-101.6015625, -100.9296875,  -85.4296875], 'latitude': [32.54681317, 32.81152175, 30.30341752], 'longitude': [-101.6015625, -100.9296875,  -85.4296875]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.reset_index()
geom = [Point(x,y) for x, y in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geom)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection=ccrs.AzimuthalEquidistant(central_latitude=90, central_longitude=0))
ax1.coastlines()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2.set_frame_on(False)
ax2.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.yaxis.set_visible(False)
gdf.to_crs("+proj=aeqd +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs").plot(ax=ax2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.margins(y=10)
```

I get this:
[image]

The coordinates are in the wrong position.

I have followed this [kaggle tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/coordinate-reference-systems) tried using this [North Pole Azimuthal Equidistant](https://epsg.io/102016) transform on the GeoDataFrame but I think I have not implemented it correctly.

The output I'm after I would like to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that without cartopy in pure GeoPandas. You just need to reproject the data correctly to Azimuthal projection (I am specifying in using proj string).

```py
proj = gdf.to_crs('+proj=aeqd +lat_0=90')
```

If you do the same with built-in world dataset, you can use it as a background.

```py
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
w = world.to_crs('+proj=aeqd +lat_0=90')

ax = w.boundary.plot()
proj.plot(ax=ax, color='r')
```

[image: resulting plot]